# PHP code with oci

Tags: php, validation, email, oci8

For email validation, the condition for checking email exist or not is failed to function and I still able to register using same email. This is code for email validation

```
if ( !filter_var($bemail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $error = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
        } else {
        **// check email exist or not**
        $result = oci_parse($connection,"SELECT BUSER_EMAIL FROM 
        POHSENG.BRONTE_USER WHERE BUSER_EMAIL= $bemail");

        $count = oci_num_rows($result);
        if($count!=0){
        $error = true;
        $emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";



        }
```

This is overall php code. I tried a lot of way to modify but it is not work at all, while in mysqli it is working.

```
<?php
require 'oci_connect_hugo.php';
$error = false;

$count="";
$bname="";
$bemail="";
$baddress="";
$bpass="";
$nameError = "";
$emailError ="";
$addError ="";
$passError = "";
if ( isset($_POST['signup']) ) {
// clean user inputs to prevent sql injections
$bname = trim($_POST['bname']);
$bname = strip_tags($bname);
$bname = htmlspecialchars($bname);

$bemail = trim($_POST['bemail']);
$bemail = strip_tags($bemail);
$bemail = htmlspecialchars($bemail);

$baddress =trim($_POST['baddress']);
$baddress = strip_tags($baddress);
$baddress = htmlspecialchars($baddress);

$bpass = trim($_POST['bpass']);
$bpass = strip_tags($bpass);
$bpass = htmlspecialchars($bpass);

// basic name validation
if (empty($bname)) {
$error = true;
$nameError = "Please enter your full name.";
} else if (strlen($bname) < 3) {
$error = true;
$nameError = "Name must have at least 3 characters.";
} else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$bname)) {
$error = true;
$nameError = "Name must contain alphabets and space.";
}

//basic email validation
if ( !filter_var($bemail,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
$error = true;
$emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
} else {
**// check email exist or not**
$result = oci_parse($connection,"SELECT BUSER_EMAIL FROM 
POHSENG.BRONTE_USER WHERE BUSER_EMAIL= $bemail");

$count = oci_num_rows($result);
if($count!=0){
$error = true;
$emailError = "Provided Email is already in use.";




}

if (empty($baddress)) {
$error = true;
$addError = "Please enter your address.";
} 
// password validation
if (empty($bpass)){
$error = true;
$passError = "Please enter password.";
} else if(strlen($bpass) < 6) {
$error = true;
$passError = "Password must have at least 6 characters.";
}
// password encrypt using SHA256();
$bpass = hash('sha256', $bpass);
// if there's no error, continue to signup
if( !$error ) {
$res = oci_parse($connection,"insert into 
POHSENG.BRONTE_USER(BUSER_NAME, BUSER_EMAIL, BUSER_ADDRESS, 
BUSER_PASSWORD)  VALUES('$bname','$bemail','$baddress','$bpass')");
oci_execute($res);
if ($res) {
$errTyp = "success";
$errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
unset($bname);
unset($bemail);
unset($bpass);
} else {
$errTyp = "danger";
$errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";   
}   
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `This function does not return number of rows selected! For SELECT statements this function will return the number of rows, that were fetched to the buffer with oci_fetch*() functions.` , [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php#refsect1-function.oci-num-rows-notes)

Comment: Check the OCI8 examples.  And never, ever, ever, do string concatenation like 'BUSER_EMAIL= $bemail"'  This is insecure.  Use a bind variable.  If this is all new to you, check http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html